# Is System.out.println() a classwide method or instance method?

Tags: java

To my belief, it would be a classwide method, since it can exist throughout the class, rather than confined to a single method. I'm not 100% sure about this however, so if anyone could provide some guidance on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `out` is a static field of the `System` class.  `println` is an instance method of the `PrintStream` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `System` class `out` is a `static` `PrintStream` instance. `PrintStream` class has `println()` method which is at instance level.

Comment: *"PrintStream class has println() method"* which is an instance method ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Ya. Added that part now . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

public final class System extends Object

The System class contains several useful class fields and methods. It cannot be instantiated.

Among the facilities provided by the System class are standard input, standard output, and error output streams; access to externally defined properties and environment variables; a means of loading files and libraries; and a utility method for quickly copying a portion of an array.

For more info check out the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is a instance method of `PrintStream` class defined in `System` class as

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```